# Inclusion of finite dimensional C*-algebras and relative commutants of subfactors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors, planar-algebras

Given a subfactor $N\subset M$ with finite Jones index, the inclusion of relative commutants $N^{\prime}\cap M\subset N^{\prime}\cap M_1$ (here, $M_1$ is the basic construction of $N\subset M$) is a unital inclusion of finite dimensional $C^*$-algebras with the corresponding Bratteli diagram connected. Conversely, if we have a connected inclusion of f.d. $C^*$-algebras $B\subset A$, does there exists a finite-index subfactor inclusion $N\subset M$ such that $N^{\prime}\cap M\subset N^{\prime}\cap M_1$ is isomorphic to $B\subset A$? If not, can we characterize such f.d. inclusion $B\subset A$ (which comes from a subfactor)?